# What are some reputable 'high risk' merchant account providers?

Tags: online-resources, tips-and-tricks, payment-cards, travel-agents, payment

I am in the planning process of starting my own travel agency business. I periodically will have to charge client's credit cards for hotel upgrades, flight class upgrades, taxes etc. I thought I would be able to use Chase bank's paymentech / orbital system, but they do not offer payment processing for travel businesses. Does anyone have recommendations or use a particular company?

P.S. I do not anticipate processing many payments the first year as it will take time to build up clientele.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about setting up a business.

Comment: That hurts my feelings, but I understand now. My apologies.

Comment: @MuyGalan Don't let it hurt your feelings. It's just the rules of the site. Welcome to TSE.

Answer (score 2):

Paypal.

They accept travel related businesses, offer functionality to accept cards in person (swipe devices), virtual terminal to process phone orders and an API to handle website transactions.  Transferring funds from your Paypal account to your bank account is fairly quick.  And they have a debit card which can be used to pay hotels and such, rather than always wiring payments.  They are also good at assisting with disputing questionable chargebacks.

We have used them for a number of years now without incident (though I am sure some horror stories will appear shortly in the comments ;-)

Of course now that I answered, this question may well be closed, as it doesn't really fall into the guidelines of TSE.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, Tom! I will definitely look into PayPal. I wasn't aware I was violating TSE guidelines. Apologies to the moderator or to whoever governs this site!

Comment: Your question is more about the travel agency business, not traveling, so the community members may vote to close your thread (that is what the close(1) indicates, one vote to close already)

Comment: I understand now. For future reference, would you be able to recommend a more appropriate forum to ask travel agency related questions?

Comment: I don't think there is travel agency site here on Stack Exchange, but there are tour operator groups on Facebook and LinkedIn.